# Is it possible to generate JSON/Dict Python object from a protobuf pb2 file?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to figure out if a protobuf descriptor or object can be converted to JSON/Dict Python object from a `pb2` file generated by `prototool`. This is what I have done so far:

1. I wrote a `config.proto` file with `TopConfig` as my message.
2. I ran `prototool generate config.proto` to generate `config_pb2.py`.
3. Now I want to generate a JSON/Dict object in Python with default values for `TopConfig`

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict, MessageToJson
import config_pb2.py

j = MessageToJson(config_pb2.py.TopConfig())
d = MessageToDict(config_pb2.py.TopConfig())
```

This results in an empty `{}` dictionary in both cases. What am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out on my own.

My mistake was that my `TopConfig` only had other `messages` nested within it but didn't have other data fields. `MessageToDict` will only work with unnested `messages`, and it will not show `enum` and `oneof` data as well.

```
MessageToDict(config_pb2.py.TopConfig())  # Will produce {}
MessageToDict(config_pb2.py.LowestConfig())  # Will produce {'k1': v1, 'k2': v2}
```

Please note that it won't show `nested messages`, `enum`, and `oneof`, you can easily have logic to check for those.

```
config_pb2.py.TopConfig().DESCRIPTOR.oneofs  # True if it has oneofs type
config_pb2.py.TopConfig().DESCRIPTOR.enum_types  # True if it has enum type
```

Hope this post helps someone down the road.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with any of the code snippets you've shown. It's just `json_format` omits that unset fields, like empty submessages. In your first example, `TopConfig()` generates an empty proto object, so the `{}` JSON representation is 100% correct.

Answer (score 0):

`json_format` will omit "unset" fields. In your example, `TopConfig()` creates an empty `TopConfig` instance, i.e. no fields are set. Therefore, `{}` is a correct JSON representation of that object.

There is, however, a [`including_default_value_fields`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/9d175493a341885019d8fad6571ddc0cf69473a2/python/google/protobuf/json_format.py#L113) to `MessageToDict` that is almost what you want:

```
including_default_value_fields: If True, singular primitive fields,
  repeated fields, and map fields will always be serialized.  If
  False, only serialize non-empty fields.  Singular message fields
  and oneof fields are not affected by this option.
```

I say "almost" because empty submessage fields would still not be present.